# knapsack problem variation with almost no constraints

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I have this variation of knapsack with very few constraints, and the lack of contraints does that i really don't know where to start.

Given a set S of positive integers. could be:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

find two non-overlapping subsets that have the same total each. The two sets do not need to contain all numbers in S.
So for the former example, the answer would be
[1,2] and [3]

Usually these problems have constraints such as the subsets needing to have specific sums, or the subsets needing to span over all elements of S.
This makes it hard for me to imagine how to solve this via bruteforce. Every time I come up with a dynamic programming table, I can't get it to cover all possible permutations of subsets

Comment: as i understand similar problems could be solved in O(n*w) for a problem with weigths, so maybe O(n*n)? but anything polynomial would probably suffice

Comment: Brute Force: Try for every sum from smallest element to total sum of elements(at least half of it).

Comment: you don't think theres any nicer way to do it?

Comment: As of now, nothing crosses my mind. Sort the dataset. Try from smallest sum till total sum. Another approach(rough idea): Sort the dataset. Keep adding element sums to maps by running a total_sum variable. If total_sum - A[i] exists in the map, maybe we have some useful information here.

Comment: will try it out, thanks

Comment: *"find two non-overlapping subsets"* Does a subset have to be contiguous? For example, is [2,5] and [7] a valid answer?

Comment: they cont have to be contigous at all [2,5] and [7] would be totally viable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem might be solved like subset sum problem in pseudopolynomial time `O(n*summ)`

We fill array `0..summ` with possible subset sums, and when we meet the same sum - we stop.

Two equal sums might be composed with some equal items - and we **just remove them**, so the rest sums contain only distinct items.

Example in Python using binary arithmetics to store sets (bit `i+1` corresponds to using i-th item in sum). `common` contains equal bits, we remove them using xor operation.

The last lines retrieve needed sets themselves.

```
L = [2,5,11,17,29,37,43]
summ = sum(L)
A =[0]*(summ+1)
A[0] = 1

X = 0
Y = 0
for i in range(len(L)):
    for k in range(summ, L[i] - 1, -1):
        if A[k - L[i]]:
            t = A[k - L[i]] | (2 << i)
            if A[k]:
                common = A[k] & t
                X = A[k] ^ common
                Y = t ^ common
                break
            else:
                A[k] = t
    if X:
        break

first = [L[i] for i in range(len(L)) if (X & (2 << i))]
second = [L[i] for i in range(len(L)) if (Y & (2 << i))]
print(first, second)

>>> [2, 11, 29] [5, 37]
```

In this example code finds equal sums `59` for `[2, 11, 17, 29] and  [5, 17, 37]` and removes common `17` to get final results with sum `42`

---

It is not obligatory to store sets in `A[]` cells - we can store the last item of sum, then unwind item sequence

```
L = [2,5,11,17,29,37,43]
summ = sum(L)
A =[0]*(summ+1)
A[0] = -1
last = 0
for i in range(len(L)):
    for k in range(summ, L[i] - 1, -1):
        if A[k - L[i]]:
            t = L[i]
            if A[k]:
                last = k
                break
            else:
                A[k] = t
    if last:
        break

first = set()
k = last
while k:
    first.add(A[k])
    k = k - A[k]

second = set()
second.add(t)
k = last - t
while k:
    second.add(A[k])
    k = k - A[k]

print(first.difference(second),second.difference(first))

>>> {2, 11, 29} {37, 5}
```